# How is the bash subshell `sed` output to be put in the main shell environment variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables

How to put the bash subshell `sed` output into the main/root shell environment variable ?

it'll fail,

```
v=`echo NO |tee >(sed 's/^/&YES/' )`
```

How's the true to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

It works (Linux Mint 18.1, GNU bash, version 4.3.48).

```
Paul--) unset v
Paul--) v=`echo NO |tee >(sed 's/^/&YES/' )`
Paul--) declare -p v
declare -- v="NO
YESNO"
```

What did you expect it to do? The issue is that you are using >( .. ), a Process Substitution syntax.

tee makes a copy of the NO and pipes it through sed. So the tee outputs the original `NO\n` to its stdout, and the sed runs as a separate process and sends `NOYES\n` to its stdout. The command substitution (in the back-quotes) collects both into `v`.

The sed runs in a separate process, and there have been issues in the past with bash not waiting for it to complete. So there is the possibility of a race condition with this construct, especially if the second process takes some time.